# svg capture using HTML canvas is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas, encodeuricomponent

I have one svg element I want to capture the svg with a html canvas. This svg elment contains one image in base64 format and some group of path.

Now the capture is working perfectly. But when I am capturing for the first time the image element is not getting capture but the group of path is captured perfectly. But 2nd time onwards  both the image and path is capturing perfectly.

Below I have given the jsfiddle url . Please help if any one can.I am trying since long time. This issue is coming on Mac Safari browser.My vesrion is 11.1 (12605.1.33.1.4). In chrome its working fine.

Open this fiddle on safari browser  and for the first time load the capture is not working. If you click run again. Its working perfectly.

So my issue is the canvas should capture the svg for the first time.

Please let me know if you need any more information on this question.
[Get the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/biswajit_rout/d7095gmu/)

```
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: the JS fiddle output is identical in my version of safari on osx 10.13.5, as it is in my version of chrome.

Comment: @StephenTetreault Thanks for your reply. I just update the question, please just have a look again. I think some issue with the image element. So do you have any idea ? How to solve it?